# how to upload image from local disk to the web using imgur api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, imgur

I want to building a file uploader app that would allow users to upload images from the local disk to the web , I search on web and find this link to use imgur api [this is url](https://ctrlq.org/code/20526-javascript-image-uploader)

but it did not work , I put the code in jsfiddle.net but also not work  [this is the link of jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2hmxt03m/)

this is the code :

```
<form id="imgur">
  <input type="file" class="imgur" accept="image/*" data-max-size="5000"/>
</form>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
     $("document").ready(function() {

  $('input[type=file]').on("change", function() {

    var $files = $(this).get(0).files;

    if ($files.length) {

      // Reject big files
      if ($files[0].size > $(this).data("max-size") * 1024) {
        console.log("Please select a smaller file");
        return false;
      }

      // Begin file upload
      console.log("Uploading file to Imgur..");

      // Replace ctrlq with your own API key
      var apiUrl = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image';
      var apiKey = 'ctrlq';

      var settings = {
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: apiUrl,
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Client-ID ' + apiKey,
          Accept: 'application/json'
        },
        mimeType: 'multipart/form-data'
      };

      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("image", $files[0]);
      settings.data = formData;

      // Response contains stringified JSON
      // Image URL available at response.data.link
      $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      });

    }
  });
});
<script>
```

so what wrong can any body help ?

**EDIT :**

I register and get the key client_id:5b9144f6bcc473e and I put the apiKey=5b9144f6bcc473e but still did not work any help

Comment: Have you registered for an API key at imgur? The API key in your code is a dummy one...

Comment: In the jsfiddle you need to remove the `<script>` tags, and include jQuery via the JavaScript settings: https://jsfiddle.net/2hmxt03m/2/ You also need to state the api key (which you can get from imgur by registering your app)

Comment: Looks like you don't have an API key, it's responding with
"{error: "Invalid client_id", request: "/3/image", method: "POST"}"

Comment: how I can to get an API key at imgur ?

Comment: ofc register in https://api.imgur.com/

Comment: ofc register in https://api.imgur.com/

Comment: I register and only get client_id and Client secret